# Can't hide html5 video in mobile by media query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I fail to hide video in mobile devise, I look through many post and tried many time, but still can't use @media to hide the video, and display an image instead. Below is my html file and css:

HTML

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <hr>
      <h2>address</h2>
        <h3>City</h3>
        <h3>email</h3>
        <p>Personal Experience</p>
        <div class="vdo">
          <video src="####" autoplay muted loop>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.container {
  background: url('hero.jpg') center center cover no-repeat;
}

.vdo {
  display: none;
}
}
```

Can someone help me out, thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. It's working fine here. https://jsfiddle.net/nhbor73m/. You can check by putting video url here.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. I'm gonna try it there right now

Comment: It does looks good. But if I use my mobile to get in. The background would simply put a big play button there.

Comment: @ketan Thanks a lot I found the issue...its because my temp saving of my mobile. It seems work find. Thank you for providing the site

Comment: You welcome. Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use.

```
.vdo {
   display: none !important;
   visibility : hidden !important;
}
```

But `display: none !important;`alone is working successfully in my PC

> NOTE : May be the problem is with your tags. Double check if there is
>   any tags that is not closed. Clear you browser cache also .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px)
{
    .vdo video
      {
        display:none !important;
      }
}
```

Comment: Your answer would have more value if you added an explanation as to why the suggestion answers the question. The underlying principle of StackOverflow is to be an FAQ site - a research tool for programming problems.

Comment: @CindyMeister : Thanks for your valuable comments and will surely improve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@media (max-width:767px){
.vdo{
display:none !important;
}
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.